# Close fragment in hanlder

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-custom-view, android-snackbar

I would like to create my own `snackbar` which extends `Fragment` class. But i am not sure to close `fragment` after couple of seconds. Because I using `hanlder` to close fragment like this:

```
private Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Fragment frag = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
            if(frag != null) {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(TAG, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    };
```

I know about expanded library but I needed custom `snackbars`.
Sometime I received:

```
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()'
> on a null object reference
```

[Edit:]

`onPause()` method I called:

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
```

Comment: Nullpointer is caused by `getActivity()` returning null. Maybe because you closed that activity. But forgot to remove the runnable from your handler. So it still gets executed, even if the activity does not exist any more

Comment: it look like app go crash but handler still wating and go crash too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fragment is not attached anymore, getActivity can return null.

Make sure you check if the current fragment is added and not detached with

`isAdded() && !isDetached()`

Comment: It crashed because `getActivity` returned null. Then you tried to call `getSupportFragmentManager` on a null object. Which will throw a null pointer exception

Comment: I will check if `isAdded() && !isDetached()` will be helpfull. Thankt you i will lete you know